# Get cross_validation_holdout_predictions() of models from a grid search

Tags: h2o

I'm trying to calculate performance in a different way how it is built in for models right now.

I would like to access raw predictions during cross-validation, so I can calculate performance on my own.

```
g = h2o.get_grid(grid_id)
for m in g.models:
    print "Model %s" % m.model_id
    rrc[m.model_id] = m.cross_validation_holdout_predictions()
```

I could just run prediction with a model on my dataset, but I think then this test might be biased because the model has seen this data before, or not? Can I take new predictions made on the same data set and use it to calculate performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to access raw predictions during cross-validation, so I can calculate performance on my own.

If you want to calculate a custom metric on the cross-validated predictions, then set [`keep_cross_validation_predictions = True`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/keep_cross_validation_predictions.html) and you can access the raw predicted values using the [`.cross_validation_holdout_predictions()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html?highlight=cross_validation_holdout_predictions#h2o.model.model_base.ModelBase.cross_validation_holdout_predictions) method like you have above.

> Can I take new predictions made on the same data set and use it to calculate performance?

It sounds like you're asking if you can use only training data to estimate model performance?  Yes, using cross-validation.  If you set `nfolds > 1`, H2O will do cross-validation and compute a handful of cross-validated performance metrics for you.  Also, if you tell H2O to save the cross-validated predictions, you can compute "cross-validated metrics" of your own.

Comment: Thanks, Erin, once again! I missed it. Somehow I thought that these two options were not there in a grid search. I think they were not there because I didn't select cross-validation option. My bad. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem!  You can pass any algorithm argument (including `keep_cross_validation_predictions`) through to `H2OGrid` -- that's how you can modify the algorithm to use non-default settings (same is true for model hyperparameters).  Examples here: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/h2o-open-tour-2016/chicago/grid-search-model-selection.ipynb